# Check for split keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios5, keyboard

As many of you know iOS 5 introduced a slick split keyboard for thumb-typing. Unfortunately, I have some UI that is dependent on the normal full-screen keyboard layout. One of my view controllers presents the user with a text entry sheet, and if they click into a textField that would be covered by the keyboard, it slides up along with the keyboard. This action is unnecessary with the split keyboard.

Is there a way to check which keyboard layout is in use before it pops up?

Thanks!

Comment: Would appreciate an update on how youve solved this!

Comment: I try answer on this question in [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17567217/887325

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When the keyboard is docked, `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` will be raised. If the keyboard is split or undocked, no keyboard notifications are raised.

If a keyboard is docked, `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` will be raised, and the following will be true:

```
[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction"] intValue] == 1
```

If a keyboard is undocked, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` will be raised, and the above statement will also be true.

Using this information has been adequate for me to code my user interface.

Note: this might be a violation of Apple's guidelines, I'm not sure.

Comment: the value for `UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction`is not correct at iOS7

Answer (score 9):

This is the solution which works with iPad split keyboards (originally from the blog linked in Zeeshan's comment)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  addObserverForName:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
  object:nil
  queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
  usingBlock:^(NSNotification * notification)
 {
     CGRect keyboardEndFrame =
     [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

     CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

     if (CGRectIntersectsRect(keyboardEndFrame, screenRect))
     {
         // Keyboard is visible
     }
     else
     {
         // Keyboard is hidden
     }
}];
```

Comment: Great, but instead of checking that the keyboard intersects the current view's frame, just check if it's on screen: CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; if (CGRectIntersectsRect(keyboardEndFrame, screenRect)) ...

Comment: @MasonLee Updated as per your comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction` key does not return 1 all the time when keyboard splits.

Below is the full user info dictionary key values on `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` / `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`.

```
2012-07-11 11:52:44.701 Project[3856:707] keyboardDidShow: {
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {1024, 352}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {512, 944}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {512, 592}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{-352, 0}, {352, 1024}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction = 0;
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {352, 1024}}";
}

2012-07-11 11:52:45.675 Project[3856:707] keyboardDidHide: {
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {1024, 352}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {512, 592}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {512, 944}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {352, 1024}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction = 0;
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{-352, 0}, {352, 1024}}";
}
```

Instead you can use `UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey` or `UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey` keys to get notified when keyboard splits.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The notifications that are posted when the keyboard appears or changes its position (`UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`) contain a `userInfo` dictionary with the frame of the keyboard (`UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`) that allows you to position your UI elements correctly, depending on the actual size and location of the keyboard.