# How to find the iPad keyboard type programmatically?

Tags: ipad, ios5, keyboard, uitextfield

How can I find the keyboard type of an iPad programmatically (i.e. dock, undock, or split), when selecting a textfield?

Comment: answers at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842806/check-for-split-keyboard may help you