# iPad split-keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ipad, keyboard-events

I am creating an app similar to the iPad's iMessage app that does messaging.  So there is an input view anchored at the bottom of the message view and input accessory view when the keyboard is shown.  Also the message view must be resized properly when the keyboard is shown while docked or undocked.

The problem I have is that the notification data that comes in from UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification is not consistent.

First, there are 3 ways that the user can undock the keyboard:

1. Press-and-hold the lower right key, then slide up
2. Press-and-hold the lower right key, when the menu pops up, select "undock"
3. Press-and-hold the lower right key, when the menu pops up, select "split"

For case #1, the notification data from UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification is consistent.  Here is the data:

```
userInfo = {
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {768, 304}}";
}
```

For case #2 and #3 the data is inconsistent, here is what I receive:

```
userInfo = {
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 0;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {768, 304}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {384, 872}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {384, 1136}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {768, 304}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameChangedByUserInteraction = 0;
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, -264}, {768, 304}}";
}
```

What is odd here is that when I listen for UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification under case #2 or #3, the data comes in as expected:

```
userInfo = {
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {768, 304}}";
}
```

Why is the notification data different?  Did anybody find a clear way to detect the split-keyboard events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No clear method haven't.

i resolve this trouble in next steps:

1. Get current orientation.
2. If orientation is Landscape then i get **height** of UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey. it must equals to 216. It means keyboard is Split mode, Else not;
3. If orientation is Portrait then i get **height** of UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey. it must equals to 216. It means keyboard is Split mode, Else not;

I update my [gist for example.](https://gist.github.com/bimawa/5963666) With convertRect method.

Comment: This is going to make it harder since iPad Mini is introduced.  I haven't even touched iOS 7 yet...

Comment: no difference. 216  is not pixels, its point parmeter independent from resolution. But this not work with iPhone 4s and 5. And iPhone not have split keyboard. They change form-factor.

Comment: Beware, this is not a good solution. Keyboard heights change depending on locale, ios version and device.

Comment: @capikaw 216 isn't static param its a number come with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`  key.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat hacky, but reliable way to determine whether the keyboard is split.

```
NSArray *classPath = @[
  @"KeyboardAutomatic",
  @"KeyboardImpl",
  @"KeyboardLayoutStar",
  @"KBKeyplaneView",
  @"KBSplitImageView"
];
UIView *splitView = textField.inputAccessoryView.superview;
for (NSString *className in classPath) {
  for (UIView *subview in splitView.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) rangeOfString:className].location != NSNotFound) {
      splitView = subview;
      break;
    }
  }
}
BOOL isSplit = [splitView.subviews count] > 1;
```

Obviously in order for this to work you need a UITextField/UITextView with a non-nil `inputAccessoryView` (you can just use an empty view for that).

*Note:* The behavior of `textField.inputAccessoryView.superview` is quite finicky, and usually depends on the keyboard having been displayed once before calling `superview`. Also to pass the App Store submission process I removed the 'UI' prefix from the private class names. That's not a guarantee Apple will not flag your app, but this approach has been used successfully before.

I've only tested it on iOS7 but if it doesn't work on other versions of iOS similar approaches could be used.

Comment: this might work but why do you access subviews 0 0 1 0?

Comment: Because it steps through the view hierarchy looking for a private class that actually renders the keyboard. I used [Reveal](http://revealapp.com) to see the find the state of the keyboard view. See [here](http://imgur.com/v8rFMKP).

Comment: It's clearly a bad idea to use this exact code in production, but hopefully the answer can still be useful for some people.

Comment: that should be done using class names at very least so it doesnt just crash

Comment: You can't use classnames because they are private, so that would not be allowed on the App Store. Obviously if you implement this in production code it should be written more safely than my short answer.  The way UIKit generates the keyboard is consistent each time, so this method does work reliably.

Comment: no. you can .. the names arent really considered off limits - the symbols are. I do it N apps and have been doing it for years

Comment: so something like if(view.className rangeOfString:@"Splitview" or className hasPrefix:@"UIButtton" ...

Comment: Oh! In that case I guess you could more reliably step through the each of children to ensure you are pulling the exact view you need. I'll update the answer with that in mind.