# Can I set the iPad keyboard to dock type/undocked type/split type via code?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard

From the device settings a user can set keyboard to dock type or split type.

For the convenience of our app can we set the iPad keyboard to dock type/ split type via code? Because sometimes a split type keyboard/undocked keyboard will be best suited for our ui. I searched a lot for any clue, but I didn't got a solution for this.

Comment: Nice question.. But I don't think this can be done as in **Apple**'s priority list first is user and then programmer. So changing the user's setting won't work. But I'm happy to see any solution for this if there exists :)

Comment: Really nice question its necessary because we developers know which kind of keyboard is suitable at some times.

Comment: take look http://stackoverflow.com/a/17567217/1597744 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/7842806/1597744

Comment: This is not a duplicate of any of the given questions - but it sure enough is close enough to get valuable information out of those.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have control over the keyboard. Your iPad app should work OK with split keyboard, docked keyboard, and hardware keyboard. Your best bet is to listen to UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification and change your UI to avoid being hidden under the keyboard frame.