# How to make InputAccessoryView appear above UITabBarViewController's tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, inputaccessoryview

I have a custom view that I am using as `inputAccessoryView` for my `tableViewController`.

the `tableViewControlleris` inside a `tabBarViewController` which is inside a navigation controller.

I managed to make the custom view appear correctly as the `inputAccessoryView`, appearing at the bottom, and when focused it goes up with the keyboard.

My problem is that it's hiding my `tabBar`, I searched but couldn't find anything except for a 2years old unanswered question.
I want my view to appear above the `tabBar`, similar to the music app when having a song playing, the song and the play button and the next button appear above the `tabBar` not hiding it.

using swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1, iOS 11 target, testing on iOS 12.1 and 12.1.1

Comment: Technically, the inputAccessoryView is "part" of the keyboard, so the tab bar shouldn't split it into. A more "compliant" solution is to move the tab bar above the keyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272267/keyboard-hides-tabbar/14782487#14782487

Comment: the inputAccessoryView does move with the keyboard, but that's not my problem, the problem is when there is no keyboard it's hiding the tabBar. i want my view to be above the tabBar, similar to musics app when you have a song player the song and play and forward buttons appear above the tabBar

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question. What I would do then is to use a subclass of `UIViewController` instead of the `UITableViewController`, with two subviews: the `UITableView` and your custom view (you can't really add a subview to a `UITableView` and `UITableViewController` requires its view to be a `UITableView`). Then you can anchor the custom view to the safe area and it should remain on top of the tab bar, and add some content inset to your table view so that it scrolls properly.

Comment: I guess I will have to do that and handle keyboard movement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to achieve this effect and made a framework called [AMKeyboardFrameTracker](https://github.com/iAmrMohamed/AMKeyboardFrameTracker) to do just that

[image: AMKeyboardFrameTracker.gif]

but first you need to understand how the `inputAccessoryView` work

`inputAccessoryView` is attached to another window called `UITextEffectsWindow` this window shows on top of your main app window

The main feature of using `inputAccessoryView` is the interactive keyboard dismissal effect with any `UIScrollView` because normally you can't get the keyboard frame from the native keyboard notifications callbacks

But with [AMKeyboardFrameTracker](https://github.com/iAmrMohamed/AMKeyboardFrameTracker) I've been able to get the keyboard frame from the `inputAccessoryView's` `superview` by observing it's frame changes, so it's still using `inputAccessoryView` but with an empty view that has no user interaction

There is an Example in the [Github repo](https://github.com/iAmrMohamed/AMKeyboardFrameTracker) you can download it and try it out

***Note***
in the example app I am using a normal `ViewController` instead of a `TableViewController` if you'd like to use a `TableViewController` you can still achieve this by adding your CustomView to the `navigationController's` `view`

Comment: your suggested lib. working on without tabbar viewcontroller ? I have face issue of - https://github.com/iAmrMohamed/AMKeyboardFrameTracker/issues/4