# iPhone keyboard is not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, keyboard

My app starts on login screen. After that I use the next code to call the TabBarViewController

```
DMMainScreenViewController *mainScreenController = [[[DMMainScreenViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"DMMainScreenViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.view.window.rootViewController = mainScreenController;
[self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and then I move to the last tab by clicking on that.

There are 2 UITextField and one UITextView and then when I touch any of them the keyboard is not showing up and I can not also change to another TextField/TextView but I can move to another tab.

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are able to touch these textfield and view?

Comment: Yes! After I touch the textfield I can see the text cursor. After that I can NOT change to any textfield/textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using IB to create your views?  If so, did you remember to wire up your UITextField to the File's owner so that view knows where to send the notifications that you clicked on your TextField?

Comment: Well, I hope so. but now I'm using UITabBar. I really gave up using that way. It could be a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

keyboard to show up immediately you'll need to set the text field as the first responder using the following line:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

but in these case of tabbarViewController, as tonklon says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510412/19679):

> If the tabbar is needed while the keyboard is visible you could only
>   move the tabbar above the keyboard, or resize the tabbarcontroller, so
>   that the tabbar remains visible.
>
> Are you sure you need the tabbar while the keyboard is visible?
>   Remember a tabbar is for changing the view. Perhaps you need to
>   rethink your interaction design.

Comment: I dont need tabbar when the keyboard is visible. I just need the keyboard but it is not working.

Comment: It never happened with me. I've no idea how to fix that. anyone?